# Aurelia - A way to add a divider into a multi level drop down menu

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a multi level dropdown menu working for Aurelia with bootstrap however whilst its three levels deep and uses as a basis THIS gist expanding on it I am having trouble adding a divider via the route settings.

Now a divider uses the class "divider" in the list tag `<li></li>` Ok so I thought by adding the entry `divider: true` in the settings for the dropdown I could check for that and instead if displaying the link etc I could instead show a divider however I dont know how to implement this into the navmenu.html file. Here is the file:

```
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li repeat.for="route of router.navigation" class="${route.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a href.bind="route.href" if.bind="!route.settings.nav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ route.settings.icon }"></span> ${route.title}</a>

                    <a href.bind="route.href" if.bind="route.settings.nav"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ route.settings.icon }"></span> ${route.title} <span class="caret"></span> <!--First level menu heading - requires route.settings.nav to exist-->
                    </a>

                    <ul if.bind="route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="!menu.navSettings.subNav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ menu.navSettings.icon }"></span> ${menu.title}</a>

                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ menu.navSettings.icon }"></span> ${menu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul if.bind="menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li repeat.for="subMenu of menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="!subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ subMenu.subNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${subMenu.title}</a>

                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ subMenu.subNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${subMenu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul if.bind="subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li repeat.for="lowestSubMenu of subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href.bind="lowestSubMenu.href"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ lowestSubMenu.subSubNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${lowestSubMenu.title}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                        
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> [ALL THE ANCHORS HERE OR A DIVIDER.. HOW DO I DO A TERNARY TO CHECK ON EACH REPEAT FOR A DIVIDER VALUE IN THE SETTINGS ARRAY. 

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Here is an exert from the route map that the navmenu reads from:

```
{
            route: "clients",
            name: "clients",
            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
            title: "Clients",
            nav: true,
            settings: {
                nav: [
                    {
                        href: "#clients/clientsList",
                        title: "Client List",
                        navSettings: {
                            icon: "list",
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        navSettings: {
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                            divider: true,  // HERE IS MY DIVIDER
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        href: "#clients/Create",
                        title: "Create Client",
                        navSettings: {
                            icon: "user",
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                        }
                    }
                ],
                icon: "user",
                auth: true,
                roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                pos: "left"
            }
        },
```

The problem is that the `<li></li>` does a repeat and I need to check in that repeat - li to see if "navSettings has an entry divider: true and if so not show the link (menu item) but instead show a line divider.

How do I discard the anchors and instead show a list line with class "divider". Whats throwing me is the fact that the li has a repeat.for and I need to either show everything between the `<li></li>`tags or instead show a divider.

I need to check on the line:

```
<li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-submenu">
```

and change the class from "dropdown-submenu" to "divider" while at the same time not show any of the anchors `<a></a>` by doing  similar check (if.bind I am guessing) for divider..

Hope you can help..

Answer (score 2):

In the `<li>` use `class="${menu.divider ? 'divider' : 'dropdown-submenu'}"`.

Use `if.bind` on `menu.divider` for the elements inside the `<li>`.

```
<li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" class="${menu.divider ? 'divider' : 'dropdown-submenu'}">
    <a if.bind="!menu.divider" href.bind="lowestSubMenu.href"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ lowestSubMenu.subSubNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${lowestSubMenu.title}</a>
    <div if.bind="menu.divider" class="divider"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Finally getting to this.. I added the above suggestion to my <li> line but am getting a warning on both options "missing attribute name" and, its not dropping down to the second level menus. Wondering if you or some one might know why typescript is complaining with the options on that ternary..

Comment: I was not aware you needed the double quotes around the whole thing. This is the answer - just forgot the double quotes.

Comment: Do you mean the double quotes around the class attribute's value? Please mark this as the correct answer.