# Aurelia - implementing a ternary for a class and getting missing attribute name

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a Typescript project and had trouble trying to display divider. I posted a question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868920/aurelia-a-way-to-add-a-divider-into-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu) and received an answer which I believe will work.

However when I tried to implement a ternary on the class I get the error `Warning Missing attribute name` on both options.

Here is my list item:

```
<li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" class=${menu.navSettings.divider ? 'divider' : 'dropdown-submenu'}>
```

I am getting the warning on both the "divider" option and the "dropdown-submenu" option. Further with this modification it now wont render the next level of menu items.

Why am I getting a missing attribute warning and how can I make this work..

**Background context**

Here is the whole navmenu:

```
                    <ul if.bind="route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" class=${menu.navSettings.divider ? 'divider' : 'dropdown-submenu'}>
                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="!menu.navSettings.subNav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ menu.navSettings.icon }"></span> ${menu.title}</a>

                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ menu.navSettings.icon }"></span> ${menu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul if.bind="menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li repeat.for="subMenu of menu.navSettings.subNav" class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="!subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ subMenu.subNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${subMenu.title}</a>

                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ subMenu.subNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${subMenu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul if.bind="subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li repeat.for="lowestSubMenu of subMenu.subNavSettings.subSubNav" class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href.bind="lowestSubMenu.href"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ lowestSubMenu.subSubNavSettings.icon }"></span> ${lowestSubMenu.title}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                        
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--<span class="divider" if.bind="menu.navSettings.divider"> </span>-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Finally here is the route containing the first level dropdown options including the divider:

```
        {
            route: "clients",
            name: "clients",
            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
            title: "Clients",
            nav: true,
            settings: {
                nav: [
                    {
                        href: "#clients/clientsList",
                        title: "Client List",
                        navSettings: {
                            icon: "list",
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        navSettings: {
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                            divider: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        href: "#clients/Create",
                        title: "Create Client",
                        navSettings: {
                            icon: "user",
                            roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                        }
                    }
                ],
                icon: "user",
                auth: true,
                roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                pos: "left"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add quotes around your `class`-attribute value:

```
<li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav" 
  class="${menu.navSettings.divider ? 'divider' : 'dropdown-submenu'}">
```